# Search Django logic

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have written the following code on my web app for searching the form. Now, I want to show error if the searched object if not found. I added the else statement at the last but it shows error.

```
def search(request):
qs = Post.objects.all()

location_query= request.GET.get('location')
details_query= request.GET.get('details')
user_query= request.GET.get('user')
days_query= request.GET.get('days')
people_query= request.GET.get('people')
date_query= request.GET.get('date')
gender_query= request.GET.get('gender')

if location_query !='' and location_query is not None:
    qs=qs.filter(location__icontains=location_query)

elif details_query !='' and details_query is not None:
    qs=qs.filter(detail__icontains=details_query)

elif user_query !='' and user_query is not None:
    qs=qs.filter(author__icontains=user_query)

elif days_query !='' and days_query is not None:
    qs=qs.filter(no_days__icontains=days_query)

elif people_query !='' and people_query is not None:
    qs=qs.filter(no_people__icontains=people_query)

elif date_query !='' and date_query is not None:
    qs=qs.filter(tour_date__icontains=date_query)

elif gender_query !='' and gender_query is not None:
    qs=qs.filter(Gender_prefer__icontains=gender_query)
context = {
    'qs':qs,
}
return render(request, 'posts/search.html',context)
```

I am trying to add this at the end:

```
return render(request, 'posts/search.html', {'error':'The keyword you entered not found!})
```

Comment: "I added the else statement at the last". I dont see the `else` statement anywhere and it would be also quite helpful to show what errors it shows, otherwise it's very difficult to provide any help.

Comment: Exaclty *what* is the error, why is the `else` missing in your code fragment?

Answer (score 0):

For your code if you would like to add error to your context use this logic.

1. Filter your queryset qs.
2. If qs is not empty context = {'qs':qs}
3. If qs is empty context = {'error': 'The keyword you entered not found!'}

so the code will look like this:

```
if qs:
  context = {
    'qs':qs,
  }
else:
  context = {
    'error': 'The keyword you entered not found!'
  }
return render(request, 'posts/search.html',context)
```